# Application_PreSendRequestHeaders() on OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I have an application that does not use OWIN middleware and has the following `Global.asax`:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
     protected void Application_Start()
     {
         //...
     }

     protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
     {
         Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
     }
}
```

This removes the `Server` header each time the application sends a response.

How can I do the same with an application that uses OWIN?

```
public class Startup
{
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder application)
     {
          //...
     }

     //What method do I need to create here?
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you have the chance to try the solutions provided with the answers?

Comment: @LeftyX At a local environment, they did not work. I have not tested in a production environment yet. Will keep you in touch.

Comment: @LeftyX Both of your answers worked on production! I chose @peco's one because I think that registering a callback to `OnSendingHeaders` is the correct way to go. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I've helped in a way. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register a callback for the `IOwinResponse.OnSendingHeaders`event:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.OnSendingHeaders(state =>
            {
                ((OwinResponse)state).Headers.Remove("Server");

            }, context.Response);

            await next();
        });

        // Configure the rest of your application...
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, HTTP responses still have the header set when they get to the browser. Can you confirm this worked for you? Other online resources suggest the header is set at a much lower level. If this only works if the site is being hosted by IIS please amend your response to clarify

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own piece of **middleware** and inject it directly into the pipeline:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            string[] headersToRemove = { "Server" };
            foreach (var header in headersToRemove)
            {
                if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(header))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Remove(header);
                }
            }
            await next(); 
        });
    }
}
```

or a custom middleware:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class SniffMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public SniffMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next): base(next)
    {

    }

    public async override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        string[] headersToRemove = { "Server" };
        foreach (var header in headersToRemove)
        {
            if (context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey(header))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Remove(header);
            }
        }

        await Next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

which you can inject into the pipeline this way:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use<SniffMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to install `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

or your middleware won't be executed in the "IIS integrated pipeline".