# Delegate Handler :Remove "Server" response header SelfHost API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

response.Headers.Remove("Server") is not removing the Server header from response,  still getting "Server--> Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"

```
 public class CustomHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {        
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                .ContinueWith((task) =>
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;                                        
                    response.Headers.Remove("Server");                                       
                    return response;
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try registering a callback for the `IOwinResponse.OnSendingHeaders` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376907/application-presendrequestheaders-on-owin/33392093#33392093

Comment: i' m using HttpSelfHostServer to host the service, not using startup class or IAppbuilder.                                                                                             var config = WcfimConfig.InitializeConfiguration(baseAddress);                config.MessageHandlers.Add(waim.GetHttpProviderHandler());
 waim.RegisterHttpConfig(config);HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);