# Azure B2C and classic ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, azure-ad-b2c, global-asax

I am looking to use Azure B2C with a classic asp.net web application. This doesn’t use any OWN middleware so I was hoping to use the Global.asax to inject the relevant tenant, client and policy info via the Application_PreSendRequestHeaders method. Can anyone tell me if this would work and if so, what names should be used when adding these values.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a prerequisite for all of the B2C authentication guides if you are building a classic ASP.NET web application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi

Some potential workarounds are:

1. You could register a callback for the IOwinResponse.OnSendingHeadersevent or create your own custom middleware to inject into the pipeline. Please see this [similar StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33376907/application-presendrequestheaders-on-owin).
2. You might be able to authenticate with the Graph API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet